# Build URL and pass it to Custom Template Tag filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Custom Template Tag filter that checks for me if the image at the given url exists:

```
from django import template
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
import urllib3


register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='file_exists')
def file_exists(filepath):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', filepath)
    if r.status == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False
register.filter('file_exists', file_exists)
```

The problem I am currently dealing with is that I need to build the url to pass it to the function.

The file path is:
static + media + id

For now, I am just trying to get a True or False with the function and later add a filepath return to  put the IMG URL in the img-tag. But for now, I just need to pass the url to the function and it is just not working.

```
<span>{{ "{% static 'media' %}/{{student.id}}.png"|file_exists }}</span>
```

returns a

```
TemplateSyntaxError at 
Could not parse the remainder:
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, are those file stored their path anywhere in the database? You just have a bunch of static files that hang around in your static directory? No `models.ImageField` or `models.FileField`? If so how did they end up being there?

Comment: Good question, the eventual goal is to implement an image upload and already have designated an ImageField there though I have not thought about it since I set it up.
So you are saying that instead of "building" the URL I could just pull it from the ImageField?

Comment: Then I suggest setting that up before dealing with images. You might already spent more time than you should on figuring out how to do this in your current way and honestly, it shouldn't even happen. If you want to migrate existing images to an `ImageField`, consider using a `data migration` to migrate your existing images under `ImageField`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Comment: You are right, thanks for your help.